# Best way to group records with MAX revision

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a source table like this:

table_a :

| id | revision | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | APPROVED |
| 1 | 1 | PENDING |

I am trying to get distinct records from table_a having the latest revision and show the latest approved revision for each one of them.

result table_b :

| id | latest_rev | latest_approved_rev |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

I have written the following query :

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.revision AS latest_rev,
       b.latest_approved_rev
FROM table_a a
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,
                       MAX(revision) AS latest_approved_revision
                FROM table_a
                WHERE status = 'APPROVED'
                GROUP BY id) b ON b.id = a.id
WHERE a.revision = (SELECT MAX(revision)
                    FROM table_a
                    WHERE id = a_id
```

My query seems to work fine, but I am wondering if I was missing something and/or if there is another way to make the query better/faster.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL; what RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: SQL is a declarative language, if your query returns the expected results then "it works". If you have a performance issue, that's a different question altogether.

Comment: "Best" is relative. However, if there are more than 2 statuses, using window functions is simpler http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/66b4f/2

Answer (score 1):

Seems you could achieve this with some (conditional) aggregation:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MAX(revision) AS latest_rev,
       MAX(CASE status WHEN 'APPROVED' THEN revision END) AS latest_approved_rev
FROM (VALUES(1,0,'APPROVED'),
            (1,1,'PENDING'))V(id,revision,status)
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a correct query (if I understand your requirement). You are very close to an ideal query. But your outer WHERE clause contains a correlated (dependent) subquery, and those don't always perform well.

You can think of this as the JOIN of two subqueries.  The one you have.

```sql
              SELECT id,
                     MAX(revision) AS revision
                FROM table_a
                WHERE status = 'APPROVED'
                GROUP BY id
```

and this one.

```sql
              SELECT id,
                     MAX(revision) AS revision
                FROM table_a
                GROUP BY id
```

You FULL JOIN them together.  Like this.

```sql
SELECT max.id, 
       latest.revision as latest_rev,
       approved.revision as approved_rev
  FROM (
              SELECT id,
                     MAX(revision) AS revision
                FROM table_a
                GROUP BY id
       ) latest
 FULL JOIN (
              SELECT id,
                     MAX(revision) AS revision
                FROM table_a
                GROUP BY id
            ) approved on latest.id = approved.id
```

In this case you can actually use LEFT JOIN because you know every id in the `approved` subquery is also present in the `latest` subquery.